What is the advantage of having a teammate on a final climb?
I have the following question on professional cycling, relating to a situation during the 2023 Tour de France (I guess it was the fifth stage). Suppose the stage ends in a climb. The two top riders for the tour classement (Pogacar and Vingegaard) aim at gaining distance to each other. In 2023, Vingegaard had better climbers on his team to assist him, like Wout van Aert. During the said stage, van Aert managed to stay in the group with the top climbers much longer than any riders from Pogacar's team. My question is the following: How exactly does this give Vingegaard an advantage to Pogacar? I would argue there is no advantage because both riders have to put in the same effort. When Vingegaard can ride in van Aert's slipstream, so can Pogacar, equivally profiting from van Aert. What am I missing?
I am aware that one may save effort since drinks are brought during the race by the teammates. But I suppose this does not play a role during the final kilometers of a stage.
